# Upload file using drag and drop and with reorder before upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to upload images with drag and drop. its working fine with any plugin with but the problem is, i need to reorder images before its uploaded to server. after searching a load i found on link but its not working as i am looking.

https://learncodeweb.com/demo/web-development/drag-drop-images-with-bootstrap-4-and-reorder-using-php-jquery-and-ajax/

Reorder like,, when you see the demo from given link,,, upload 2 or 3 images and you can reorder them before clicking upload button and it should be uploaded in order we sort but its not happening... to reorder the image i have to wait for upload an then i can reorder image and save order to server that's the problem i am facing

Comment: How it should get reorder? And paste the code that you have tried so that anyone here can help you out quickly.

Comment: I am using the same code showing in this tuts..  
 https://learncodeweb.com/demo/web-development/drag-drop-images-with-bootstrap-4-and-reorder-using-php-jquery-and-ajax/

Comment: See my answer if it helps you.

Comment: Reorder like,, when you see the demo from given link,,, upload 2 or 3 images and you can reorder them before clicking upload button and it should be uploaded in order we sort but its not happening... to reorder the image i have to wait for upload an then i can reorder image and save order to server that's the problem i am facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link for `drag and drop images with reordering`. Check this out if it helps you.

Link: http://demos.codexworld.com/drag-drop-images-reorder-using-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/

Comment: I need to sort image before it get uploaded to server

Comment: Check my updated link. Do you want something like this?

Comment: understand my question first what i am looking for

Comment: So first you want to upload the image then you want to reorder it. Right?

Comment: flow i want is ... when you select multiple images to upload then i want to sort using drag and drop then i click button to upload that's i want